# GDI Objects not deleting

Tags: vb.net, gdi

I've been asked to debug some code that is trying to make a movie of a graph in VB.Net, by saving a screenshot to a BMP. I have discovered that it is failing after it hits the limit of 10,000 GDI objects and determined that the leak is from this code:

```
Dim r As Integer
Dim hdcdest As System.IntPtr = CType(CreateCompatibleDC(CInt(GetWindowDC(frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Handle))), IntPtr)
Dim hdcbitmap As System.IntPtr = CType(CreateCompatibleBitmap(GetWindowDC(frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Handle), _
                                                            frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Size.Width - (0 + CropRight), _
                                                            frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Size.Height - (10 + 0)), IntPtr)
SelectObject(hdcdest, CInt(hdcbitmap))
BitBlt(hdcdest, 0, 0, frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Width - (0 + CropRight), frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Height - (10 + 0), _
GetWindowDC(frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Handle), 0, 10, 13369376)

Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(hdcbitmap)

r = DeleteDC(CInt(GetWindowDC(frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Handle)))


DeleteObject(CInt(hdcdest))
DeleteObject(CInt(hdcbitmap))
```

And BitBlt declared as:

```
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "GDI32" (ByVal hdestDC As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, _
        ByVal nwidth As Integer, ByVal nheight As Integer, ByVal HsrcDC As IntPtr, ByVal xsrc As Integer, ByVal ysrc As Integer, ByVal _
        dwRop As Int32) As Boolean
```

The 2 `System.IntPtr` creation calls create 2 GDI objects each and the 'BitBlt' creates 1. The issue I've found is that the `DeleteObject()` calls only remove 1 GDI object each.

So are the delete calls being done incorrectly? or is there other objects floating around with GDI objects that are not being deleted?

Comment: Your pinvoke declarations are bad, get better ones from the pinvoke.net web site.  There are many leaks, one is caused by your SelectObject() call.  You must store its return value and call SelectObject() again to restore the original selection before you destroy the device context.  You are also forgetting to destroy the GetWindowDC() return value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [GetWindowDC function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144947(v=vs.85).aspx)

> GetWindowDC is intended for special painting effects within a window's nonclient area. Painting in nonclient areas of any window is not recommended.
>
> After painting is complete, the ReleaseDC function must be called to release the device context. Not releasing the window device context has serious effects on painting requested by applications.

Your code is calling GetWindowDC in multiple places.  Try calling it only once into a variable, and then use the ReleaseDC on it after you are done.

Comment: That worked fantastically! using `Dim MainWindowDC As System.IntPtr = GetWindowDC(frmDynamicsMDI.MainControl.fraAnimation.Handle)` and then calling `DeleteDC(MainWindowDC)` successfully cleaned up the resources

Comment: @user3565590 Don't ignore the ReleaseDC, and also the suggestions from Hans' comment regarding the SelectObject function.

Comment: How does the ReleaseDC differ from the DeleteDC? doesn't the delete still release the resources?

Comment: @user3565590 You didn't create the DC, you borrowed it, so you should release it, not delete it.  It is, after all, still being used by the object where it came from.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, I updated it to release instead. Thanks